# Replacing String in Java to get all variations

Tags: java, string, combinatorics

I'm trying to get a printout of all variations of a certain String. For example, we have this input: AB0C0. The 0 in the 3rd and 5th spots should be treated as variables. The variable characters are 1, 2, and 3 to be placed in the spot of 0. This means there would be all possible variations of this input:

1. AB1C1
2. AB2C1
3. AB3C1
4. AB1C2
5. AB1C3
6. AB2C2
7. AB2C3
8. AB3C2
9. AB3C3

This is just an example. A 5-character long string is a place for 1 to 5 variables. The issue I'm facing is, that it should generate all variations no matter how many variables are in the input in no matter in which place they are.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the key consisting of 5 characters:");
String input = scanner.next();
String strOutput1 = input.replaceFirst("0","1");
String strOutput1A = input.replace("0","1");
String strOutput2 = input.replaceFirst("0","2");
String strOutput3 = input.replaceFirst("0","3");
String strOutput4 = input.replaceFirst("0","4");
String strOutput5 = input.replaceFirst("0","5");
System.out.println(strOutput1.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(strOutput1A.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(strOutput2.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(strOutput3.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(strOutput4.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(strOutput5.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Based on what are the variables in your example assigned the values 1,2 and 3 ? because number of known characters in the string is 3? namely, A,B and C?

Comment: @MarwaEldawy 0 is a variable that should be detected from the input. So A, B and C are known and shouldn't be changed. Another example: A00BC, there we again have 9 different combinations with numbers 1, 2 and 3: A11BC, A12BC, A13BC, A21BC, A22BC, A23BC, A31BC, A32BC, A33BC.

Comment: I understand this example. My question is: If we have a string like this: A00BCDE. What values should 00 take? 1,2 and 3 also? What about this example: A0000 ? what values should 0000 take ?

Comment: Or maybe you mean the string will always contain 5 characters, with 2 variables?

Comment: @MarwaEldawy There are always 5 characters where we can have one to four zero's, that need to be replaced with our values, that are always 1, 2, 3. By math, with two variables we get 3^2=9 combinations, with 3 variables we get 3^3=27 combinations, and with 4 variables we get 3^4=81 combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the key consisting of 5 characters:");
    String input = scanner.next();

    //find positions of '0' in input
    List<Integer> varPositions = findVarPositions(input);

    //create permutations
    List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
    permutations.add(input);//AB0C0
    for (int position : varPositions) {
        permutations = permutateAtPosition(permutations, position);
    }

    //print permutations
    for (String permutation : permutations) {
        System.out.println(permutation.toUpperCase());
    }
}

private static List<Integer> findVarPositions(String input) {
    List<Integer> varPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    int lastVarPosition = -1;
    while ((lastVarPosition = input.indexOf('0', lastVarPosition + 1)) != -1) {
        varPositions.add(lastVarPosition);
    }
    return varPositions;
}

private static List<String> permutateAtPosition(List<String> partialyPermutated, int position) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] replacements = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
    for (String item : partialyPermutated) {
        for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
            String output = replaceCharAt(item, position, replacements[i]);
            result.add(output);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String replaceCharAt(String input, int position, char replacement) {
    //converting to char array, because there's no method like
    //String.replaceAtPosition(position, char)
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    charArray[position] = replacement;
    return new String(charArray);
}

}
```

It's not fixed to a number of variables.

The idea is to extract positions of '0' and subsequently call the method `permutateAtPosition`, which takes a partially permutated list and permutates it by one more level.

For "a0b0c0" and values 1-2 it would be `['a0b0c0']`, then `['a1b0c0','a2b0c0']`, then `['a1b1c0','a1b2c0','a2b1c0','a2b2c0']`, and finally `['a1b1c1','a1b1c2','a1b2c1','a1b2c2','a2b1c1','a2b1c2','a2b2c1''a2b2c2']`.

This solution keeps everything in memory, so in the general case (unlimited input string) it would be wiser to go with depth-first instead.

Comment: Does perfectly the job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've got another solution for you.
First step, getting the amount of variables:

```
int variableCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == '0') {
        variableCount++;
    }
}
```

Then calculating the amount of results we are expecting:

```
int countMax = (int)Math.pow(4,variableCount);
```

Lastly, count up in base 4. Pad the number with 0's and replace the original input 0's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countMax; i++) {
    String paddedNumbers = format("%" + variableCount + "s",Integer.toString(i, 4)).replace(" ", "0");
    int replacedCount = 0;
    char[] outputChars = input.toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (input.charAt(j) == '0') {
            outputChars[j] = paddedNumbers.charAt(replacedCount);
            replacedCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(outputChars);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I really like the concept, because it's so universal to use for more cases. Could you further elaborate how to deal with the "format" defined in the last String? I don't see another reference to it in the code.

Comment: Yes, it's String.format(). What it does is formatting a string and inputs variables to that string. In this case I used the padding function to add spaces in front of the actual number so "3" becomes " 3" if variableCount is 2. Those spaces get then replaced by 0's. So it becomes "03" instead.